# ApplySymbologyFromLayer not including all values in my domain

Tags: arcpy, layers, point, symbology, template

I am using a combination of ArcMap and ArcPy to stage data for sharing as a hosted Feature Service on AGOL.

The data will be used in a data-driven pages type of way, where each feature will be reviewed and have a 'ReviewStatus' attribute updated before moving to the next feature for the same review.

The way I have it set up, every feature has a default value in my tracking field of 'Awaiting Review'. As the feature is reviewed, a field is updated to indicate whether the changes were 'Accepted', 'Rejected', or 'Marked for Revisit'.

To facilitate this, I have created and applied a domain consisting of only those four values discussed above and created a layer file symbolizing each value as a different color.

When I have all my layers loaded on my desktop session, I am attempting to loop through each layer and apply the symbology from my staged layer file. The issue is...each feature has a default value of 'Awaiting Review', so before any review has happened, there are no features with any other values in my domain. When I use the ApplySymbologyFromLayer tool, it only brings the symbology for 'Awaiting Review'. It ignored 'Accepted', 'Rejected', and 'Marked for Revisit'.

I have tried messing with FeatureTemplates to no avail.

The manual workflow that HAS been successful is to simply import the layer file as symbology through the layer properties. When I close the properties dialog, everything works as expected. It is trying this pythonically that fails.

In my routine, I have also tried the layer method addAllValues() AFTER applying symbology and before. I even tried to reload the symbology after adding all values.

I know arcpy.mapping can be a bit clunky sometimes and often needs some inelegant workaround to accomplish a task, but am I missing something? Is there a way to include the symbology for ALL values in a layer file even if the dataset doesn't yet contain features with all those values?